# Springboot Twitter Binding API Authorization

Tags: java, spring, twitter

i want to make my springboot application can connect into twitter through API using my secret and client key. Here it is my code

```
package com.backend.siap.controller;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Tweet;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestTwitter {



    @Autowired
    private Twitter twitter;


    @RequestMapping(value="twitter/{hashTag}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public List<Tweet> getTweets (@PathVariable final String hashTag)
    {
        return twitter.searchOperations().search(hashTag, 5).getTweets();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="timeline", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public List<Tweet> getTimeline()
    {
        return twitter.timelineOperations().getHomeTimeline();
    }

}
```

if i call getTweet method controller it return json that contain some tweet that i search using hashtag. so it work

but if i call getTimeline method controller it return something like this

```
org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.
```

I also have added my secret and client code in my application properties.

how to solve that problem? thanks

Comment: You have `spring.social.twitter.appId` and `spring.social.twitter.appSecret` properly configured in `src/main/resources/application.properties`?

Comment: yes i did configure it @LucianovanderVeekens

Comment: maybe this is also the problem in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739751/spring-social-twitter-missingauthorizationexception