# spring social twitter MissingAuthorizationException

Tags: twitter, authorization, spring-social

I tried to post a tweet using Spring Social as described in this tutorial: https://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/. However I am getting

```
org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException: Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.
```

My code looks as follows

```
TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate = new TwitterTemplate("key", "secret");
TweetData tweetData =new TweetData("test screenshot").withMedia(new ByteArrayResource(object.getScreenshot().getBytes()));
Tweet postResult = twitterTemplate.timelineOperations().updateStatus(tweetData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

certain operations require a separate access token to be passed along with TwitterTemplate:

```
new TwitterTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
```

access tokens can be generated here: apps.twitter.com/app/"appId"/keys